# Numbering coordinates and drawstring from left to right

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, emgucv, drawrectangle

I'm trying to number blobs using the rectangle COG of objects. But the rectangles are in an elliptical path, hence I'm not getting it in a proper sequence.

```
Font annotationFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
Pen annotationPen = new Pen(Color.FromName("White"), 2.5f);

Graphics g = imageBoxMain.CreateGraphics();
for (int i = 0; i < totalrectcount; i++)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(arrayX[i] /* blobid[i].name.Length * 6)*/, imageBoxMain.Image.Height - arrayminY[i]- 6, 100, 20);

    g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(i + 1), annotationFont, annotationPen.Brush, new System.Drawing.Point(rect.X, rect.Y));
}
```

This is what im getting :

[image]

I want the rectangles to be labelled from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two arrays, one for your X and one for your Y?

```
//far left is number 1, far right is 2, middle is 3
var arrayX = new[] { 100, 300, 200 };
var arrayY = new[] { 100, 95, 130 };
```

That's gonna be a pain in the ass; convert them to a single array of `Point` first, then sort them, then draw them:

```
var points = new Point[arrayX.Length];
for(int x = 0; x<points.Length; x++){
  points[x] = new Point(arrayX[x], arrayY[x]);
}

foreach(Point r in points.OrderBy(p=>p.X)){
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(r.X /* blobid[i].name.Length * 6)*/, imageBoxMain.Image.Height - r.Y - 6, 100, 20);
  g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(i + 1), annotationFont, annotationPen.Brush, new System.Drawing.Point(rect.X, rect.Y));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, if I order it by X as you said it works. BUT only when there is one row of rectangles. If there are 3 rows, it orders it from top to bottom. and If I order it by Y, then the same thing happens as my original problem.

Comment: At the time I posted my answer, you hadn't said there were multiple rows of rectangles. You're going to have to show your array contents if you want dedicated help with that one. It will probably look something like `points.OrderBy(p=>(int)(p.Y+5)/100).ThenBy(p=>p.X)` - this turns all your slight variations in Y values (100,95,130,200,195,230) into simply numbered rows(1,1,1,2,2,2), orders by them by y then by x, then plots the rectangles in left to right top to bottom order

Comment: my arrayX[x], arrayY[x] has the X and Y coordinates of the green rectangles you see in the image. Im getting those coordinates from the blob rectangle method of aforge.

Comment: points.OrderBy(p=>(int)(p.Y+5)/100).ThenBy(p=>p.X) this worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I noticed you said "if there are 3 rows" but your question picture only contains two. Please take this as a learning experience on SO; we can only use the information you tell us to answer a question, if you don't give all the information up front then it gets quite tiresome for the person trying to help you if you keep changing the question and pointing out why their answer to your old question doesn't fit your new question. Glad I could help! If you find that numbers are jumping onto different Y rows you might need to adjust the 5 and 100 values a bit

Comment: The 5 takes care of the slight up down variation in the boxes, the 100 is the height of the line (the difference in pixels between the Y of eg box 1 and box 4) not the height of the box. I haven't measured your image - I really need to see your arrays to recommend proper values